# Prove: If $ (a^2 \mid (2b^2))$, then $ (a \mid b). $

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

### Trying to prove the following implication:

$$ (a^2 \mid 2b^2) \implies (a \mid b) $$

---

Knowing that I've tried to prove it by using Bézout's Theorem only to find myself lost.
My teacher hinted that we can use either prime factorization or prove that $(a\wedge b=a)$.

Comment: Try taking the first step: $a^2\mid 2b^2\implies a^2\mid b^2$.  From there it should be trivial.

Comment: What is $(a\wedge b=a)$?

Comment: @Ovi Apparently, $a\wedge b$ denotes the greatest common divisor.

Comment: @egreg Ah ok thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use *valuations*: for any prime $p$ and any integer $n \in \mathbb N$, denote by $v_p(n) \in \mathbb N$ the power of $p$ in the prime factorization on $n$. Then, the hypothesis translates as 
$$v_p(a^2)=2v_p(a)\le v_p(b^2)+v_p(2)=2v_p(b)+v_p(2)\le2v_p(b)+1, $$
so that $\;v_p(a)\le v_p(b)+\frac12$.